# maatwebsite~2.1.0 : Datetime column in exported xls file shoud have Excel date formatting

Tags: php, laravel, maatwebsite-excel

I am trying to export time column as a Excel time format but for some reason It doesn´t work.

```
$array_tytan_info_ntt= TYTAN_INFO_NTT::whereDate('fec_startdate', '>=', $variable)
->selectRaw(" TIME(fec_startdate)  as 'STARTDATE1' ")
->get(); 

$excel_tytan_info_ntt = json_decode( json_encode($array_tytan_info_ntt), true);

Excel::create('ntts_mes_'.Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString(), function($excel) use($excel_tytan_info_ntt) {
$excel->sheet('nttsmes', function($sheet) use($excel_tytan_info_ntt) {

$sheet->setColumnFormat(array(
'A' => 'hh:mm:ss',));
$sheet->fromArray($excel_tytan_info_ntt);
});
})->export('xls');
```

As you can see, return as a String.

[image]

Expected behaviour

[image]

Many thanks for any help. Regards.

Comment: check it out, https://laravel-excel.maatwebsite.nl/docs/2.1/import/dates

Comment: just read. cant see anything about that